# Install MSIX packaging tool on windows server 2019

Tags: packaging, windows-server-2019, msix

Does anyone know how I can install MSIX Packaging Tool on a windows server 2019 (1809). On a windows 10 desktop I can just download it from the windows store but server doesn't have access to the store.

Can it be downloaded as an offline install?

I can copy the binaries across from a windows 10 machine and it appears to work fine but this isn't ideal in a corporate environment and I'm not sure by doing this it would break any Terms.

Thanks